# Spring Boot Elasticsearch Configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I've got a working Spring Boot Elasticsearch Application which uses one of two profiles:  application.dev.properties or application.prod.properties.  That part works fine.  I am having issue with getting the external elasticsearch to read from the application.xxx.properties.

This works:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:config/elasticsearch.properties")
public class ElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public Client client() {
        TransportClient client = new TransportClient();
        TransportAddress address = new InetSocketTransportAddress(
                environment.getProperty("elasticsearch.host"), 
                Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("elasticsearch.port"))
        );
        client.addTransportAddress(address);        
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
    }
}
```

but obviously doesn't solve my multi-environment issue.

I've also tried @Value annotations for host and port variables without success.

How can I convert the above to read its values from the application properties file or choose a different @PropertySource file based on whichever profile I want to run?

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.host = 10.10.1.10
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.port = 9300
```

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you just using Spring Boot but trying to work around it. Spring boot already loads a property file based on the profile you select. So you are basically making it to hard ... Also Spring Boot already configures ElasticSearch for you, so why are you trying to do it yourself again..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Remove your configuration class and properties.

Add the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Just add the `spring.data.elasticsearch`  properties to an `application-prod.properties` and `application-dev.properties` and change for the desired environment. This is described in the [ElasticSearch section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html#boot-features-elasticsearch) of the Spring Boot guide.

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=10.10.1.10:9300
```

The value in either file will of course differ (or put the default in the `application.properties` and simply override with an `application-dev.properties`.

Spring Boot will based on the `spring.profiles.active` [load the desired properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) file.

There is no need to hack around yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Whenever I try to use just the properties without the custom configuration, it always runs the internal in memory Elasticsearch and not my external server.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case if you specify the cluster-node properties (this is also explained in the reference guide).

Comment: I did read the reference guide on ES.  Something else I'm doing must be conflicting with the spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes line in the application properties.  That's why I tried manually creating the configuration.

Comment: You have created the correct properties file(s) the names used in your question aren't the ones Spring Boot is picking up? You don't have a typo in your configuration? You are really using Spring Boot and the 1.2.x version?

Comment: I created a whole new project using just the config as you recommended and it does start the transport node.  So I need to move elements from my existing project over to see what breaks it.  Thanks again!

Comment: @JoeReymann I was running into the same problem and one thing that did the tricky for me was checking out which files were placed into `/target` directory by Maven. I don't know if you're using Maven but, if it's the case, it's worthy to verify if intended files are propertly compiled into appropriate folders.

Comment: Wow.  I was using the raw spring-data elasticsearch dependency.  Switching to the spring boot starter elasticsearch resolved my issues.

Comment: @M.Deinum what if my server needs username & password how I should add those credentials in spring boot?

Comment: Depending on your driver you can just set them (check the spring boot documentation for that).

Comment: looks like `spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name` is deprecated :-/ https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.transport

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Deinum, if you are using Spring boot it will get the properties from the active profile active.

I have different profiles in my project and this is my elasticsearch configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticSearchConfiguration {
    @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name}")
    private String clusterName;
    @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes}")
    private String clusterNodes;
    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate() throws UnknownHostException {
            String server = clusterNodes.split(":")[0];
            Integer port = Integer.parseInt(clusterNodes.split(":")[1]);
            Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("cluster.name", clusterName).build();
            client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build()
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(server), port));
            return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client);

    }
```